# Firebase Chart Visualization Failed to Show Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a medical app that needs to show their short medical profile and a chart of it. For Database, I use Firebase as BaaS. I need help, because my chart can't show the data. I am using Mike Phil's Chart to help me show my chart. Everytime I put the chart code into DataSnapshot, it doesn't work, but if I put it outside DataSnapshot, it works, but it can't show the data from the firebase. Here is the code:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
    private ImageView profilePic;
    private TextView profileName, profileAge, profileEmail, profileHeight, profileWeight, profileListening, profileSights, profileHeadSize, profileBirthday, profileBirthMonth, profileBirthYear;
    private Button profileUpdate, buttonSign;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private BarChart graphView;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    String profileImageUrl;
    Uri uriProfileImage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    LineGraphSeries series;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listString = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        profileName = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
        profileAge = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileAge);
        buttonSign = findViewById(R.id.buttonSign);

        profileUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnProfileUpdate);
        profileHeight = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileHeight);
        profileWeight = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileWight);
        profileListening = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileListening);
        profileSights = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileSights);
        profileHeadSize = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileHeadSize);
        profileBirthday = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileBirthday);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);



        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();



        loadUserInformation();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        DatabaseReference childReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(databaseReference.getKey());

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);

                profileName.setText("Name: " + userProfile.getUserName());
                profileAge.setText("Age: " + userProfile.getUserAge() + " years old");
                profileHeight.setText("Height: " + userProfile.getHeight() + " cm");
                profileWeight.setText("Weight: " + userProfile.getWeight() + " kg");
                profileHeadSize.setText("Head Circumference: " + userProfile.getHeadSize() + " cm");
                profileListening.setText("Hearing: " + userProfile.getListening());
                profileSights.setText("Eye Sight: " + userProfile.getSights());
                profileBirthday.setText("Date of Birth: " + userProfile.getBirthday() + " / " + userProfile.getBirthdayMonth()+ " / " + userProfile.getBirthdayYear());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        /** START OF GRAPH VIEW CODE **/

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);

                int height = Integer.parseInt(userProfile.getHeight());
                int weight = Integer.parseInt(userProfile.getWeight());
                int headSize = Integer.parseInt(userProfile.getHeadSize());

                graphView = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.graphView);

                graphView.setDrawBarShadow(false);
                graphView.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
                graphView.setMaxVisibleValueCount(120);
                graphView.setPinchZoom(false);
                graphView.setDrawGridBackground(true);

                ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, height));
                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, weight));
                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, headSize));
                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, 36));

                BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Data Set 1");
                barDataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
                BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet);
                data.setBarWidth(0.4f);

                graphView.setData(data);

                String[] xaxisgraph = new String[] {"BBb", "TGb", "Pen", "Pel", "Paj"};
                XAxis xAxis = graphView.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(xaxisgraph));
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);




                /** END OF GRAPH VIEW CODE **/

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });






        buttonSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();// optional depending on your needs
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        profileUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, UpdateProfileActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }

    public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

        private String[] mValues;
        public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
            this.mValues = values;
        }


        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return mValues[(int)value];
        }
    }



    private void loadUserInformation() {
        final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl().toString())
                        .into(profilePic);
            }


        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uriProfileImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
                profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        StorageReference profileImageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        if (uriProfileImage != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();// optional depending on your needs
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

    }

    private void showImageChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Profile Image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the graph code in a function and then insert it into the data snapshot.